# Transcribe excel columns into MSproject columns using excel VBA

Tags: excel, vba, ms-project

I'm trying to do two things (a) OPen a new file in MS Project (success), and then transcribe information in a column in excel (A2:A10000) to a column in MSProject called "Name", which is the Object (I believe) of the Task Name.  I will be doing other transcribing (for example B2:B10000 into "Start" or start date in Project, but that code will follow the same logic as below - so once I get this column to transcribe, I will write the code for the other columns (by the way right now the code is similar for all columns, and they all skip over that command without updating MSProject).

```
'open a new project file in MSProject

Set pjapp = CreateObject("MSProject.Application")
If pjapp Is Nothing Then
    MsgBox "Project is not installed"
Exit Sub
End If

pjapp.Visible = True

Set newproj = pjapp.Projects.Add
newproj.Title = "ExcelExtract"


'Copy and paste from excel to MSProject

Dim wst As Worksheet
Set wst = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Project_Outline")

Dim tsk As Task 'NOTE:  I have turned on Microsoft Project Reference Library.  In VBA Excel -> Tools -> (checkbox) "References MS Office Project"
Set wsOuts = wb.Sheets("Project_Outline")

Set wsTaskList = wsOuts.Range("A2:A10000")


For Each tsk In ActiveProject.Tasks
    If Not tsk Is Nothing Then 'ERROR:  this code gets skipped over and is never seen
        tsk.Name = tsk.wsTaskList
    End If
Next tsk
```

Comment: Does `ActiveProject` have any tasks anyways? Any reason you're not using `newproj` here? Also, `tsk.wsTaskList` looks problematic. A [`Task`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/project.task) does not have a `.wsTaskList` property.

Comment: FYI: Project's [Import Wizard](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/import-excel-data-into-project-cb3fb91a-ad05-4506-b0af-8aa8b2247119) makes quick work of this, no coding required.

Comment: Note: generally speaking, Start and Finish dates are not entered--they are calculated based on the network (tasks linked to each other), duration, calendars, etc.

Answer (score 0):

lyonsguy, Several hours after I posted the first answer I realized you want to run the macro from Excel. That's a little more challenging since Excel has an open format so the code is totally dependent on how the Excel Workbook is set up. This is the sample Excel workbook I used for the Excel code below.
[image]

And this is the macro to export the data. But as Rachel rightly notes in one of her comments, Project calculates dates based on entered task durations and dependencies. Start and Finish dates should NOT be directly entered either manually or via code as that sets a constraint and effectively nullifies Project's scheduling engine. Nonetheless, here is the macro to run from Excel.

```
'Macro written by John - Project
'Version 1.3 5/28/14 2:00 pm
'   *added declaration for index variables
'   *included separate procedure for checking object library references
'   *changed array dimension statements for active selection so procedure works with consolidated files
'   *changed all constant designations for line feed and carriage return
'   *added declaration for remaining undeclared variables
'   *changed code to recognize and handle vertical tabs
'   *fixed problem with writing to caption that occurs with some Windows installations
'   *changed export to scheduled start/finish instead of baseline start/finish
'   *added Resource Names field to export and version number as variable
'   *added statement to reset "on error goto" after Excel is called
'   *added format for date value in Excel to only show date without the time
Option Explicit
Option Compare Text
Public Const ver = " - 1.3"

Public Prj As MSProject.Application
Public t As Tasks
Public UID As Single
Public DurVal As Single, HPD As Single, HPW As Single, cf As Single
Public NumRows As Integer, i As Integer, p1 As Integer
Public c As Range
Public curcel As Variant    'could be either a number or text
Sub Excel_Export_To_Project()

MsgBox "This macro exports the following data fields to Project:" & vbCr & _
    "    Task Name" & vbCr & "    Outline Level" & vbCr & _
    "    Duration" & vbCr & "    Start" & vbCr & _
    "    Predecessors" & vbCr & "    Resource Names" & vbCr & _
    "    Task Notes", vbInformation, "Excel to Project" & ver
    
'First, count rows in Excel worksheet
'   (assumes first row is header, if there is none remove the "-1")
NumRows = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(1).UsedRange.Rows.Count - 1

'Second, open an instance of Project or if already open, use that file
On Error Resume Next
Set Prj = GetObject(, "MSProject.application")
If Err <> 0 Then
    On Error GoTo 0
    Set Prj = CreateObject("MSProject.Application")
    If Err <> 0 Then
        MsgBox "MS Project is not available on this workstation" _
            & vbCr & "Install Project or check network connection", vbCritical, _
            "Excel to Project - Fatal Error"
        FilterApply Name:="all tasks"
        Set Prj = Nothing
        On Error GoTo 0     'clear error function
        Exit Sub
    End If
    
End If
On Error GoTo 0
Prj.Visible = True
Prj.FileNew
Prj.DisplayAlerts = False
'find the default hours per day and hours per week settings for Project
HPD = Prj.ActiveProject.HoursPerDay
HPW = Prj.ActiveProject.HoursPerWeek

'Now, read each row of data from the worksheet and export to Project
Application.Caption = "Progress"
ActiveWindow.Caption = " Reading worksheet and exporting"
Set c = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(1).Range("B2")
Set t = Prj.ActiveProject.Tasks
For i = 0 To NumRows - 1
    t.Add.Name = c.Offset(i, 0).Value
    'find the unique ID of the task just added
    '   (facilitates expansion of the macro for increased functionality)
    UID = t(c.Offset(i, 0).Value).UniqueID
    t.UniqueID(UID).OutlineLevel = c.Offset(i, 1).Value
    'skip remaining columns for this row if this is destined to be a summary line in Project
    '   (Project calculates duration and start and best practices dictate no resources assigned)
    If c.Offset(i, 2).Value <> "" Then
        DecodeXLDurUnits
        t.UniqueID(UID).Duration = DurVal
        t.UniqueID(UID).Predecessors = c.Offset(i, 3).Value
        t.UniqueID(UID).Start = CStr(c.Offset(i, 4).Value)
        t.UniqueID(UID).ResourceNames = c.Offset(i, 5).Value
        t.UniqueID(UID).Start1 = CStr(c.Offset(i, 4).Value)
    End If
    t.UniqueID(UID).Notes = c.Offset(i, 6).Value
Next i

'Finally, close and exit
MsgBox "Data Export is complete", vbOKOnly, "Excel to Project"
Application.Caption = ""
ActiveWindow.Caption = ""

End Sub
'This routine determines if duration column in Excel is in minutes, hours, days or weeks
'   (most likely units) and then adjusts the data accordingly for import to Project
Sub DecodeXLDurUnits()
    curcel = c.Offset(i, 2).Value
    'default if duration column is in minutes
    p1 = Len(CStr(curcel)) + 1
    cf = 1
    If InStr(curcel, "h") > 0 Then
        p1 = InStr(curcel, "h")
        cf = 60
    ElseIf InStr(curcel, "d") > 0 Then
        p1 = InStr(curcel, "d")
        cf = HPD * 60
    ElseIf InStr(curcel, "w") > 0 Then
        p1 = InStr(curcel, "w")
        cf = HPW * 60
    End If
    'convert duration value to be in minutes for Project import
    DurVal = CSng(Mid(curcel, 1, p1 - 1)) * cf
End Sub
```